# Where the Pending Changes in TFS 2010 stored?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have some questions regarding TFS 2010 please:

1- Where the pending changes are stored when using TFS 2010 (When you make changes to a file and close Visual studio without checking it in where these changes stored)
I beleive they are are not stored in the workspace.

2- When youopen Visual Studio and open the file from the workspace the changes appear in the file.
I am so confused about that. Can someone explain to me how this works please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make changes without checking in, the modifications are stored locally  but the file is flagged as "modified by" on the tfs. If you want to store the modifcations on the server without checking in you can use the shelving functionality.

Comment: This also implies that when a file is modified outside of visual studio, it will not be included in "Pending Changes" unless you explicitly select "check out for edit" on the file. An extremely annoing narrow minded ignore-the-complete-outside-of-the-center-of-the-world-microsoft-application "feature".